# Computing loss in Deep Q Learning having a Q network with multiple outputs

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, q-learning

I am currently trying to understand and implement DQN on a small self-coded snake replica. I can't find anything specific regarding this problem, every DQN tutorial/explanation I come across tends to bounce around this subject without addressing the technical aspects of it, which leads to my problem:

If I am not mistaken every time we train the Q network the loss is computed with **x** and **y**.

- **x** being [Q(s)]
- **y** being calculated through the Bellman Equation -> [R(s') + y*max(T(s'))], T being the target neural network used to compute the Q target values.

The problem is both Q() and T() return multiple outputs, one for every possible action, and loss should be computed regarding only the Q value correspondent to the action **a** actually taken by the agent to get it from state **s** to **s'**.

This sounds simple in theory but I can't figure out how to implement it using Keras fit(), the loss function can't access action since it takes only two parameters (y_true, y_pred) both containing all possible Q values.
I tried to simply calculate the max Q inside a custom Keras loss function but had no success because the agent is not always going to pick the action with the largest Q due to the exploration/exploitation epsilon.
I still don't know how to make the model calculate loss using only Q from [state, action] pair. Do I need to pass this information to fit somehow? I have tried looking into Keras backend and callbacks but I am afraid I am overcomplicating what was supposed to be a straightforward part of the algorithm.

My question is: Is there a conventional/simpler way to do it? Am I missing something important?